# Using pipe() after child calls exec()

Tags: c, pipe, exec, parent-child, ipc

My end goal is to have a parent process pass lines of text to the child, then the child process will print the text to stdout. The child is to run "permanently" in the back ground while the parent gets user input and pass's it to the child. I prefer the child in a separate program. Differentiating between child and paretn through if statements is messy as fudge.

I was looking into pipes but I'm unsure if it's even possible for pipes to communicate between a parent/child after the child has called `exec()` to a different program.

Is this possible? If so, is there any example you can point me to? If not, what method of IPC can I use in that case?

Comment: https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html

Comment: I think I jumped the gun and will gladly remove my comments - which will make @amon's appear rather odd. Glad to see you got an answer.

Comment: @amon - I'm removing my comments (see comment above)

Comment: Thanks kevin. No worries. I will be removing mine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard scenario is to have the program executed as a child be agnostic of the pipe and just use `stdin` / `stdout`. You achieve this by `dup2()`ing the respective end of the pipe as fd `0` or `1` (or both with two pipes for bidirectional communication), corresponding to `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO`. After this, exec your child program.

Of course, there are alternatives like e.g. "named pipes" if you need `stdin` / `stdout` for a different purpose in the child.

Still if you write both parts yourself, you might want to think about simpler solutions:

> Differentiating between child and parent through if statements is messy as fudge.

You have to do this anyways, at least for wiring up the pipes and calling exec(). Just create separate code files and call things like `parent_main()` and `child_main()` as appropriate (whatever you like to call them).

Comment: Thanks, your answer was what I needed. Thank you. I like the way you simplified the parent-child to have to not look as messy as I originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

After exec*() functions the child shares all the file descriptors of the parent process. So if you create a pipe before fork() you have access to read/write fd in both of them.

Usual method is:

- create a pipe (a read fd, a write fd)
- fork()
- in parent:

  - close read fd (you will not read from parent here)
  - write data into write fd
  - wait/die
- in child:

  - close write fd (you will not write from child)
  - read data from read fd
  - wait/die

Can't see why you want to exec a new process. If really needed you have to use standard stdin/stdout (see other answer) or have a program that will accept a fd (filedescriptor, an integer) as parameter in order to know which one is the pipe. Don't seems very nice to me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is much easier to do it with [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) which manages the communication channels automatically

> `FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);`
>   The popen() function shall execute the command specified by the string
>   command. It shall create a pipe between the calling program and the
>   executed command, and shall return a pointer to a stream that can be
>   used to either read from or write to the pipe.
>
> The environment of the executed command shall be as if a child process
>   were created within the popen() call using the fork() function, and
>   the child invoked the sh utility using the call:
>
> execl(shell path, "sh", "-c", command, (char *)0);
>
> where shell path is an unspecified pathname for the sh utility.
>
> The popen() function shall ensure that any streams from previous
>   popen() calls that remain open in the parent process are closed in the
>   new child process.
>
> The mode argument to popen() is a string that specifies I/O mode:
>
> If mode is r, when the child process is started, its file descriptor
>   STDOUT_FILENO shall be the writable end of the pipe, and the file
>   descriptor fileno(stream) in the calling process, where stream is the
>   stream pointer returned by popen(), shall be the readable end of the
>   pipe.
>
> If mode is w, when the child process is started its file descriptor
>   STDIN_FILENO shall be the readable end of the pipe, and the file
>   descriptor fileno(stream) in the calling process, where stream is the
>   stream pointer returned by popen(), shall be the writable end of the
>   pipe.
>
> If mode is any other value, the result is undefined.
>
> After popen(), both the parent and the child process shall be capable
>   of executing independently before either terminates.
>
> Pipe streams are byte-oriented.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion, popen() shall return a pointer to an open
>   stream that can be used to read or write to the pipe. Otherwise, it
>   shall return a null pointer and may set errno to indicate the error.

For example suppose you want to send `Hello world` to the child:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  FILE* toChild;
  toChild = popen("./child", "w");//child is executable of the other file: change the name
  int res = fputs( "Hello World\n", toChild);
  pclose(toChild);
  return 0;
}
```

and the child:

```
int main()
{
  char p[100];
  int n;
  do{
    n = scanf("%s", p);
    if (n>0) {
    printf("INPUT MESSAGE: \"%s\n\"", p);
    //free(p);
    }
    else {
      printf( "%d, No matching characters\n", n);
    }
  }while(n>0);
  return 0;
}
```

You can also use `scanf("%ms", &p)` with `char* p` and then `free(p)` if you are on a pure POSIX system (not on OSX).